# What is the maximum size of payload I can send in a request to AWS API Gateway RestAPI which acts as proxy to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-rest-api

I understand I can use a private RestAPI as a proxy to S3, so what I am interested in here is understanding the constraints on the request payload.
What is the maximum size of the payload I can send in request considering that RestAPI is in between? Does this impose any constraints that I need to be aware of vs. direct to S3 requests?

Is the max size configurable?

Answer (score 0):

There are [couple of limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) for the payload that can be sent or received through API Gateway -

> 1. Payload size - 10 MB
> 2. Total combined size of request line and header values - 10240 bytes

Both of these are hard limits and ***cannot*** be increased.

However, there is a workaround the payload limit. Instead of directly uploading/downloading the S3 object through API Gateway, you request a pre-signed URL from API Gateway for the S3 bucket and redirect the client to it to. Check out details on this suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967547/api-gateway-get-put-large-files-into-s3).