# AWS Lambda - why is it rejecting my request with 413 content too long error when it's well under the published 6MB limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Using Amplify, I have API Gateway and Lambda set up. API Gateway has published payload limit of 10MB, Lambda has published payload limit of 6MB. My request, consisting of a FormData and other metadata, comes out to be a little over 3MB.

I am using express and http-proxy-middleware to route my requests.

Comment: Did you ever find a reason for this? I'm having similar issues and would be keen to have any insight.

Comment: @kaskelotti No, I didn't. I just ended up using the workaround described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899319/aws-large-file-upload-api-gateway-lambda-best-practices